# grepping parameters from statement

Tags: regex, parsing, grep

I have a statement that looks something like this:

```
DO prog3 WHILE prog1 arg1 arg2 <= prog2 arg1 END
```

I would like to extract the parameters `prog3`, `prog1 arg1 arg2`, `<=` (which could be any operator), `prog2 arg1` from the statement, using grep-style regex.

My command is:

```bash
grep -E 'DO(.*)WHILE(.*)[<=](.*)END' <<< \
'DO prog3 WHILE prog1 arg1 arg2 <= prog2 arg1 END' -o
```

The regex works on regex101.com, but not in grep, which simply returns the whole statement as a match, ie

```
DO prog3 WHILE prog1 arg1 arg2 <= prog2 arg1 END
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` doesn't output all capture groups. It would be better to use `sed` like this:

```bash
s='DO prog3 WHILE prog1 arg1 arg2 <= prog2 arg1 END'
sed -E 's/DO (.*) WHILE (.*) ([<>=]+) (.*) END/\1\n\2\n\3\n\4/' <<< "$s"

prog3
prog1 arg1 arg2
<=
prog2 arg1
```

Here:

- Used `[<>=]+` in a separate capture group to grab operator text
- Used spaces around capture groups to handle greediness of `.*`
- Use `\n` after each back reference to print each group on a separate line like `grep -o`

Answer (score 2):

With `perl` one-liner you could try following code. Written and tested with your shown samples Only. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0LXL6T/1) for used regex in Perl program.

```
perl -pe 's/\bDO (.*?) WHILE ([^=><]*) ([=><]+) (.*?)\bEND\b/$1\n$2\n$3\n$4/' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
prog3
prog1 arg1 arg2
<=
prog2 arg1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above used regex.

```
\bDO         ##Matching word boundary followed by DO here.
(.*?)        ##Creating 1st capturing group putting a lazy match to get values just before next mentioned value.
 WHILE       ##Matching space followed by WHILE.
 ([^=><]*)   ##Matching space and creating 2nd capturing group which matches anything apart from = < >
 ([=><]+)    ##Matching space and creating 3rd capturing group where matching 1 or more occurrences of > < OR =
 (.*?)       ##Matching space and creating 4th capturing group with a Lazy match in it.
\bEND\b      ##Matching word boundary followed by END followed by another word boundary here.
```